# Intall php5.2 on WHM 58 Cpanel EasyApache 4

Tags: centos, cpanel, whm

I needs to install php5.2 version on my server. Right now php 5.4 is the oldest version installed. Since 2 days. I searched a lot over google but didn't find appropriate guidance yet. Tried a lot of tutorials no works at all. Any suggestion or guidance will be appreciated. thanks

Comment: 5.2? Normally I would have *some* sympathy and understanding of having to use something older. [But 5.2 is pretty much insane](http://php.net/eol.php).

Comment: Some of my applications support 5.2.

Comment: yes as said. That's pretty insane.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any proper or easy way to revert to php-5.2.x from php-5.4.x; at least not using WHM interface or as an automatic process. Even if you have EasyApache3 you will not be able to downgrade from php-5.4.x to php-5.2.x

Your only option might be CloudLinux which comes with a php selector which allows you to select any php version from php-5.1.x to php-7.x.

You must know that Cloudlinux is not free and the license is around $10/month. They offer a 15 day trial so if you do all the necessary setting within that period you can just use it as much as you want. You won't be able to update it though and some of the functionality might not work as expected after the trial ends.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP versions that you have mentioned are completely outdated and using them would be risky. Cpanel is never going to support it with their newer version. So your best deal would be to update your application/website to latest PHP and host with the latest PHP only